# Should I fix this obscure but elegant c++ code fragment?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I came across this elegant piece of code, which, however, relies on an obscure but fundamental low-level characteristic:

```
std::string file_path_leaf( std::string const & path )
{
    auto const pos = path.find_last_of("/\\"); // windows or posix
    return path.substr( pos + 1 ); // a walk on the wild side?
}
```

In the edge-case (where 'find_last_of' fails) it works correctly, i.e. it leaves the string alone. But is it too obscure?

Comment: Hmmm.. `size_type` is guaranteed to be unsigned, and `npos` is guaranteed to be its [largest possible value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos). So adding 1 to it has to get you 0. Looks kosher to me.

Comment: Yes. Right now it works correctly. Also it is remarkably concise.  However it relies on two assumptions, one of which could change anytime.  The assumptions are (1)  adding 1 to the maximum value of an int will wrap around to 0, and (2) a 'not found' return value from 'find_last_of' will use this particular value.  Bugging me.

Comment: There's a very important difference between "it works correctly" and "it is guaranteed to work correctly on all compliant implementations".

Comment: The [language-lawyer] tag implies you want to know what the Standard says about the code's behavior, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking. Or is it?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it should be guaranteed by the standard as unsigned overflow is well-defined behavior, as opposed to signed

Comment: Sure, what does the standard say about the code's behavior? (If you have the inclination). Thx.

Comment: I guess changing the type declaration from 'auto' to 'size_t' (or maybe 'unsigned long') would at least make assumption (2) explicit. Might cause the compiler to complain if assumption (2) was violated.

Comment: "Should I fix this obscure but elegant c++ code fragment?" Are you code golfing? No? Then fix it. Not only it's obscure, but *looks like a bug* to a casual code review.

Comment: Note that there *is* a bug, not where you're looking but somewhere else. A POSIX filename can contain a backslash (a Windows filename cannot contain a slash, though).

Comment: Comments are for explaining why some elegant piece of code works, and how it handles corner cases.

Answer (score 7):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos `npos` is in fact `...a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type size_type`. Cross-checked with the C++11 standard you can find this spelled out in 21.4/5, the class definition.

Then also unsigned arithmetic is equally guaranteed by the standard to wrap around, so the code is perfectly well-defined.

That said you can still make clarity arguments for changing it. At the very least add a comment stating how it works for future maintainers.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the comment there "//a walk on the wild side?" is similarly elegant but too concise.

Comment: That comment tells me nothing about what's going on.  It's neither elegant or helpful to a future maintainer.  Something like `// If no separator is found, pos will be the max value of a size_t, so this will wrap around and we'll return a copy of the full path` would be a useful comment.

Comment: Or you could write `if(pos == std::string::npos) return path;` which would state the intent similarly, but wouldn't be, you know, a comment. Descriptive programming and like.

Comment: Yes. @Miles. The comment is more of a "heads up" than an explanation. Of course I could rename the function "the_lou_reed_way_to_get_the_file_path_leaf" thus triggering a research project into late 20th century Brooklyn culture. Just joking, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: the code is almist certainly safe, but you could make it bulletproof by changing `pos + 1` to `pos + 1U`. That will avoid an obscure corner of the integer promotion rules which could only be triggered by a perverse (but legal) implementation.

Thanks to @T.C. for a useful discussion which helped me remove a number of irrelevant sidetracks from this answer.

1. `basic_string::find_last_of` has return type `size_type` ([string.find.last.of] 24.3.2.7.5/p1) which is an unsigned integer type ([allocator.requirements] 20.5.3.5/Table 31). (In fact, this is almost certainly `std::size_t` since `std::string` uses the default allocator, whose `size_type` type member is `std::size_t`, according to [depr.default.allocator] D.10/p1.)
2. The value returned by `basic_string::find_last_of` in the case that the searched object is not found is `basic_string::npos` ([string.find.last.of] 24.3.2.7.5/p2), which is `size_type(-1)` ([basic.string] 24.3.2/p5.1).
3. It is highly likely (but not guaranteed) that `size_type` will have an integer rank greater than or equal to `int`. If that is the case, then in the computation `pos + 1`, the 1 will be converted to `size_type` prior to doing the addition, and the addition will then be between unsigned integer values. The rules for unsigned integer arithmetic guarantee that the result of adding an unsigned 1 to an unsigned -1 must be 0.
4. If `size_type`'s rank is less than that of `int`, then the result will depend on the relationship between `numeric_limits::max<size_type>()` (which is precisely the value of `npos`) and `numeric_limits::max<int>()`:

   1. If `numeric_limits::max<size_type>() > numeric_limits::max<int>()` (which implies that `size_type` and `unsigned int` are the same size, even though they are different types), then `pos` will be "promoted" to an `unsigned int` and then the `1` will also be converted to `unsigned int`. The result will be the same as above.
   2. If `numeric_limits::max<size_type>() < numeric_limits::max<int>()`, then `pos` will be promoted to a (signed) `int`, and the addition will be signed. But given the inequality, `pos + 1` cannot overflow. The result could be too large to fit into a `size_type`, of course, but the conversion from  signed to unsigned integer types is well-defined and if `pos == npos`, the result is guaranteed to be 0.
   3. That leaves only the case where `numeric_limits::max<size_type>() == numeric_limits::max<int>()`. One theoretical possibility for this equality would be that `size_type` is precisely one bit shorter than an `int`.  Such an implementation would be weird, to say the least, but it is still legal. In this case, `pos` will be promoted to (signed) `int`, `1` will remain a signed `int`, and if `pos == npos`, the signed addition `pos + 1` will 
      overflow, creating Undefined Behaviour.
5. To summarize, the computation is unsafe if `size_type` has a smaller rank than `int` but has the same maximum value. I have a hard time believing this situation would ever occur in real life but I believe that it would not violate the C++ standard.

   To protect yourself from the above extremely unlikely case, it is sufficient to change the expression to `pos + 1U`. That will guarantee that `pos` is converted (if necessary) to an `unsigned int` to match `1U`, after which the addition will be performed as unsigned arithmetic with no possibility of UB, and the result when `pos == npos` (after truncation to the size of `size_type`) will be 0.

Comment: The member's name is `size_type`, not `size_t`. Besides, OP's using `std::string`, which uses `std::allocator`, so `size_type` *is* `std::size_t`. And if `size_t` is small enough to be subject to integral promotions, then the more likely problem isn't `npos + 1` causing an overflow; it's that it doesn't yield zero, and that problem isn't fixed by using `1U`.

Comment: @t.c.: it will be truncated to 0 when the sum is converted back to the original type (as argument to the `substr()` member function). I thought I mentioned that but it may well have been underemphasized. So the problem will be fixed by changing 1 to 1U because the only problem is a possible signed overflow.

Comment: @t.c.: you're probably right that I confused the types; I'll recheck it all in the morning when my eyes are working again. It doesn't really matter; nowhere does the standard put any constraint on `size_t` other than that it must be unsigned. So it could be tiny or gigantic.  (There's a recommendation that it not be wider than unsigned long so a recommendation that it nit be narrower than unsigned int wouldn't be out of place. But I don't think there is one.)

Comment: You are right on the truncation part. I need to fix my brain compiler...

Comment: Per [basic.fundamental]/3, "the value representation of each corresponding signed/unsigned type shall be the same". Since a padding bit is not part of the value representation but a sign bit is, you can't have a case where the unsigned type has a padding bit where the corresponding signed type has a sign.

Comment: @t.c.: Do you have a citation for `std::allocator`'s `size_type` being `std::size_t`? I can only find the `make_unsigned_t<std::ptrdiff_t>` which I mentioned.

Comment: It's living in [depr.default.allocator] right now, but is likely to be undeprecated (apparently there are implementations where `make_unsigned_t<ptrdiff_t>` isn't `size_t`, so removing it and deferring to the default in `allocator_traits` will break code).

Comment: @t.c. I think that's a misreading of what it means for value representations to correspond but it's way too late here to count angels. I'll reply tomorrow. (My use of the word padding was imprecise. It's not that the sign becomes padding; it's that it's forced to be 0.)

Comment: If that bit is not padding ("forced to be 0") and hence is part of the value representation, then that means operations on that unsigned type whose maximum is 2^N-1 must obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^(N+1), because there are N+1 bits in the value representation (including the forced-to-be-0 bit). That's absurd.

Comment: @T.C.: that would indeed be ridiculous, so I guess it comes back to what is meant by "the value representation of each corresponding signed/unsigned type shall be the same". The C standard is much clearer that the unsigned type can have the same number of (non-sign) bits as the corresponding signed type, and Appendix C does not provide any hint that this is an incompatibility between C++ and C. As I realised later, none of this matters to my answer because nothing stops an implementation from having a 31-bit (for example) `size_t`. So I edited the answer to focus on the essentials. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

JoeMo:

I thank you for your thoughtful and well-researched responses to my question.

I actually did change it (along the lines suggested by milleniumbug:*(if(pos == std::string::npos) return path;* etc.). 
Also, I agree with him or her that the code looks wrong.

The reason why the code looks wrong is also why it seemed 'elegant'; one pass through the code handles all the different cases. There are no if statements etc., just two straight statements. Can't be that simple, can it?

But it accomplishes this feat of simplification by making use of specialized knowledge at different levels of abstraction (bit-wize knowledge of the *string::npos* value, the way that *substr* works in edge-cases, etc.).

Better to keep things at the same level of abstraction, even at the cost of a little extra code.

Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Regardless of whether the given code exhibits correct behavior or not, it is still broken or at least is rather fragile because it relies on some bold implicit assumptions instead of making those assumptions explicit and verified. It can be improved without modifying original logic by adding a couple of assertions:

```
std::string file_path_leaf( std::string const & path )
{
    auto const pos{path.find_last_of("/\\")}; // windows or posix
    assert((std::string::npos == pos) || ((std::string::size_type{0} <= pos) && (pos < path.size())));
    static_assert(std::string::size_type{0} == (std::string::npos + std::string::size_type{1}));
    return path.substr(pos + std::string::size_type{1});
}
```